# Dropdown Events don't after on the AJAX response content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a page where the list of CHAPTERS are visible in the SIDEBAR and the DETAILS are loaded from the database. When user selects a CHAPTER from the sidebar, the details are loaded using jquery AJAX request. The details section also has a language translation option. After the AJAX response, the dropdown is present but doesn't fire the AJAX request. I used jQuery 'on' method to perform the AJAX call, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone please help me solve this problem? I have attached screenshot of my code and my page as well.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCS4p.png)
[My Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIHdq.png)

Comment: Post your code instead of image

Comment: $('select#language-selector').on('change',function(){
var translation_lang = $('#language-selector option:selected').attr('name');
var translation_section_id = $('#chapter-sidebar > .active-chapter').attr('name');
                 
    /*To make an AJAX call to retrieve selected section data*/
    $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'section-translate.php',
  data:{
   id:translation_section_id,
   lang:translation_lang
  },
  success:function(translated_section){                   
         $('#chapter-translation').html(translated_section);
  }
 });
});

Comment: $('#chapter-sidebar li').on('click',function(){
    var new_chapter_id = $(this).attr('name');
    
 $('#chapter-sidebar li').removeClass('active-chapter');
 
    /*To make an AJAX call to retrieve selected chapter data*/
    $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'chapter-fetch.php',
  data:{
   id:new_chapter_id
  },
  success:function(new_chapter){
   $('#chapter-content').html(new_chapter);
   
  } 
 });

 $(this).addClass('active-chapter');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following script for this

```
$(document).on('change','select#language-selector', function() {
    //your code here
})

$(document).on('click','#chapter-sidebar li', function() {
    //your code here
})
```

> $(document).on('change','select#language-selector', function() { will bind the event on the `select#language-selector` elements which are not present at the time of binding event. This is called as event delegation.
>
> Whereas $("select#language-selector").change(function () { will bind events only to the `select#language-selector` elements which are present in DOM.

Comment: Can you please tell me as to why my code wasn't working before? The ids and classes were present, but the events were not getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

First check you include jquery library or not than use.

```
  $(document).on('click','#id',function(){
     //your code here
  })
```